# D3js - change line color based on dataset

Tags: d3.js

I need to change line color if value is under 0. Using other words, for positive points i want the line to be blue and for negative red.

I dont know if d3js v4 can handle this kinda of issue.

Thanks!

Comment: could you add the code your using now ... what data point do you want to use to determine the colour? .. lines have x1, y1 and x2, y2 .. all of which could be positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gradient.

From an adaptation of https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/c022f78e258d869f5ebae54d7fc20aed

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg').style('background-color','#ddd')

var linearGradient = svg.append("defs")
            .append("linearGradient")
            .attr("id", "linear-gradient")
            .attr("gradientTransform", "rotate(90)");

        linearGradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "0%")
            .attr("stop-color", 'blue');

        linearGradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "50%")
            .attr("stop-color", 'blue');
                    linearGradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "50%")
            .attr("stop-color", 'red');


        linearGradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", 'red');
            
var data = [];

var min = -10;
var max = 10;

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 99]).range([0, 600]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min, max]).range([300, 0]);


for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
}


var line = d3.line()
.x((d, i) => xScale(i))
.y(d => yScale(d));

const g = svg.append('path')
.datum(data)
.style('fill','none')
.attr("stroke", "url(#linear-gradient)")
.attr('d', line);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="width:600px; height: 300px;"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I tried to use linegradient and the result is the following, not exactly what i wanted (i want the lines under 0 to be red)

The code:

```
    var yMin = d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return parseFloat(d.y);
    });
    var y0 = yMin-margin.bottom;
    if (yMin < margin.bottom) {
        y0 = -5;
    }
    if (y0 > 0) {
        y0 = -5;
    }

    var yMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return parseFloat(d.y);
    });
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([y0, yMax + 10])
        .range([height, 0]);

   svg.append("linearGradient")
        .attr("id", "line-gradient")
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", yScale(yMin))
        .selectAll("stop")
        .data([
            {offset: "0%", color: "red"},
            {offset: "50%", color: "red"},
            {offset: "50%", color: "lawngreen"},
            {offset: "100%", color: "lawngreen"}

        ])
        .enter().append("stop")
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; })
```

[image]